# How to include a filter for PDF documents in Windows 7 (64 Bit) file open dialog

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to include PDF files (or any other type of file) in the default Windows 7 (64-bit) file open dialog. The image below will illustrate what I want to say:

[image]

The way I see it, this includes all native Microsoft file types.

Comment: There is no default list: it's a program duty to populate it. Type `*.pdf` in the file name text box to filter all PDF files. Keep in mind force-opening an unlisted extension might not give the desired result, considering it's unsupported. In fact, it might not work at all.

Comment: To use `*.pdf` just remember to select `All files` in the file type menu. I could be a bit more helpful if you could mention the program you are using and what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: @and31415 Typing the extension is not feasible everytime..

Comment: @AshishKulkarni Program is Outlook 2013, to insert attachment. I use the 'All Files' option as of now, then try to locate the document by name.. I was looking if those options could be modified in the dropdown...

Comment: @Firee Those options are probably hard-coded into the program. Unless Outlook 2013 provide some way to customize the list (which I doubt), you would need to patch it yourself to replace an existing file type with PDF.

Comment: @Firee - I just checked in outlook 2013, and selecting the "All word Documents" shows up both doc, docx files AND pdf files too. There is no switch for pdf specifically.

Comment: There is no solution here. You cannot change the program's hard coding itself.