# Making Windows 7 default to "All Files" when opening a document?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, erp

I'm taking over an old coworkers job and part of that means I'll be working on various IFS tickets without any real ERP experience.

I'm working with one user who is trying to check in documents in IFS. Right now, IFS defaults to JPEGs and then she has to select "All Files" in order find PDFs.

Example:

[image]

As much as I'd like to say "it's one extra step, come on" the user's manager has insisted it interrupts her workflow and asked us to get on it.

I've spoken with our IFS experts and they're unaware of any setting that would make the open dialog default to All Files in IFS. I've searched in Google for any setting in Windows 7 that would do that - but those have been unsuccessful - I keep getting results about changing which program opens a specific file type.

Comment: You can't make Windows 7 default to all files (or whatever) because the open dialog is created by the application itself: the OS just displays it as requested. If the specific program doesn't provide a built-in way (documented or not) to change the order, the only solution is to hack it yourself, completely ignoring possible legal issues. For what is worth, by typing `*` in the **File name** text box and pressing Enter, you will see all files - regardless of the currently selected type; by using `*.pdf` you will see just PDF files, and so on.

Comment: Related: [How to include a filter for PDF documents in Windows 7 (64 Bit) file open dialog](http://superuser.com/q/715819/289138)

Comment: entering a filter into the filename-field does nothing. If it WOULD do something that'd be a pretty serious, security-related bug

Comment: @specializt Here's a working example using Notepad: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zwCju.png

Comment: im guessing you dont know what "working example" means .... well, nevermind, here is reality : http://s1.directupload.net/images/140826/nms22sk2.png

Answer (score 0):

The setting your "experts" are "unaware of" is called [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx), its a pretty standard way of defining file-extensions which are selectable or even preselected. Simply put in `All files (*.*)|*.*` as the first element in the string and you're good to go, the order in this string will be the order in which elements in the dropdown are available / preselected - you can also change the preselection with [FilterIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filterindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also : this is a question about programming, not systems integration / administration.

Comment: Look, I asked the people at my company who've been doing it longer than I have. "Filter, its a pretty standard way of defining file-extensions which are selectable or even preselected. Simply put in All files (*.*)|*.* as the first element in the string and you're good to go, the order in this string will be the order in which elements in the dropdown are available / preselected - you can also change the preselection with FilterIndex" would have been sufficient.